# PIL works for eclipse but not for Pycharm. It always shows a moduleNotFound error

Tags: python, eclipse, pycharm

I am trying to make a simple Python GUI program. I have finished the code, but when I tried to run the same code on Eclipse and Pycharm. The code works on Eclipse but not in Pycharm. It always shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'. I don't know how to solve this problem because this seems to have something to do with Pycharm IDE itself. Any idea or suggestion to solve this problem? I am using Python 3.8 by the way

Comment: Where is the configuration of PyCharm? How are we supposed to know what the problem is? Please provide all the information on the project & IDE settings you are using.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1 x64 if that's what you asking

Answer (score 2):

PIL is not installed by default in PyCharm. You need to go to *Settings/Project:your-project/Project interpreter* hit the install button (right of the module list) or Alt+Insert. Then search for PIL, it should be the top result and then hit the *Install Package* button in the bottom left.

Comment: It shows a error like this, Collecting PIL

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL